# Background not repainting itself

Tags: java

This code repaints a random oval, rectangle, and line with different colors on the screen. The problem is that I'm trying to change the background color each time it repaints, but the backgrounds doesn't repaint. Please help.

```
package events;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint extends JPanel {

static Paint g;

boolean change = true;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);

}

void circles() {
    Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    repaint();
}
```

}

Comment: `Paint paint = new Paint();` is creating a new `Paint` instance in addition to the one you already have. That's not going to change the one you're *in* will it?

Comment: I thought it calls the constructor which repaints the background, since everytime you creates an object it uses the constructor. how would i change the background then?

Comment: Hmmm. I did put the setBackground inside the paint method first, but it didn't paint the background. I search for why, and someone said that you have to make the panel opaque first, so I tried setting it to opaque inside the method, but that didn't work either. So I search again, and someone said you have to put it in a constructor, so I did that and it work. The only problem is that I can't repaint it.

Comment: I would highly recommend against calling `repaint()` in any of the painting methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the static Paint variable. Your class doesn't need any static variables.

> how would i change the background then?

The painting method should NOT change the properties of the class. It should only paint the component based on the current properties.

So you need to do something like:

1. Create a method like `setRandomBackground()`. This method will create a `Color` object that you can use in the `paintComponent()` method. At the end of this method you should invoke `repaint()`, which will tell Swing to paint the component.
2. Get rid of `new Paint()`
3. get rid of `Thread.sleep()` // never tell a painting method to sleep.
4. get rid of `repaint()` // never tell a painting method to repaint itself, this will create an infinite loop.

Finally, read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to learn the basics.

Also, variable names (R, G, B) should NOT be upper cased.

Comment: I have problem calling repaint in non paint methods. It says symbol repaint not found.

Comment: @Ski, the code must be in your  "Paint" class. Update your question with your new code, since your old code is completely wrong.

Comment: Get rid of the static Paint variable. It is not needed. What is the point of your circles() method. You create a hardcoded Color object but this is not a random color like you had before. Also, you don't reference this object in the paintComponent() method so invoking repaint() won't do anything. You don't have super.paintComponent(). I didn't tell you to remove that code. I have no idea where the NullPointException is occurring, so you need to look at the stack trace which tells you the line of code causing the problem and then fix the problem.

Comment: @Ski, Finally, why have you not read the tutorial link I provided? Start with a working example so you understand the basics of how painting works. Then make small changes, one at a time, such as creating the "setRandomBackground()" method like I suggested. Once you understand the basics you modify your current application.

Comment: Like this part   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }

Comment: It's declaring methods inside another method. How is that even possible?

Comment: And it doesn't explain what invokeLater(new Runnable mean)

Comment: You said don't use the repaint method inside paintComponent, but right now it's the only way I can use it without the screen erasing everything. I tried reading on how to do it without putting it inside the paintComponent, but none of it makes sense, and I can't do it.

Comment: God. Really? It actually works when I put everything else on the outside,and put repaint on the inside of the paintComponent method.

Comment: `I did read it, but it doesn't explain anything.` of course it does. It gives you working example code and explains step by step why you override paintComponent() and shows how to use super.paintComponent(). Llearn by example. Regarding the other methods, that has nothing to do with custom painting (so of course a "painting" tutorial won't explain it) and is standard code for creating a GUI, which you should already know! If you don't know what it is, then read the tutorial section on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more basics.

Comment: `put repaint on the inside of the paintComponent method` - that is 100% wrong. This creates an infinite loop. Forget about your current code. Start with the tutorial example. If your changes don't work, then you have a proper `SSCCE` to post. And if you don't know what a `SSCCE` is then search the forum/web.

Comment: Everytime I try to put repaint in the main method an errors comes up that says that a non static method cannot be reference in a static method.

Comment: My suggestion was to create a custom method in your class ("setRandomBackground()") and then I said in that method you invoke repaint(). The main method does not need to invoke repaint() on the panel. Its like when you use setText(....) on a JLabel, you don't invoke repaint, the label will paint itself. In your case you called the method "Circles", so you just invoke the Circles method. Of course nothing will happen because you aren't generating a random color and your painting code is not using the color either, so you need a variable to store the color so the paint method can use it.

Comment: Actually, the repaint method is working now, but i still don't know how to use bufferimages so the panel doesn't get erase every time.