# I can't call the repaint() method in my main method

Tags: java

Everytime I try to call the repaint() method it says a non static method cannot be reference from a static method. Btw, it's in the same class as the paintComponent method. I tried to create an object out of the class first, then reference it with the object name but it also didn't work. Please help.

```
public class P extends JPanel {

P g = new P();
boolean change = true;
static int x = 0;
static int y = 0;
static Color CircleC = new Color(0, 0, 0);
static String position = "";
P p = new P();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(CircleC);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(position, x, y + 25);

}



public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
p.repaint();

}

}
```

Comment: You're breaking the paint chain, you must call super.paintComponent before your perform any custom painting, otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of nasty paint artefacts

Comment: Okay. After I add it, how do I use the invokeLater method? I put the invoke later method inside a while loop but it only prints the circle once??? why?

Comment: Start by getting rid of "static P g = new P();" and in fact, you shouldn't rely on static, it is not a cross object communication mechanism and will only make your life more difficult

Comment: Okay. I got rid of it. Now what?

Comment: Why are you wasting peoples time????  Every suggestion here was made in your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29052567/131872, you were told to read the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting`. You where also told to forget your current code and start with an example from the tutorial. The code you posted here is completely wrong and looks nothing like the code in the tutorial.

Comment: I read it. It didn't make any sense.

Comment: @ski, what didn't make sense? Did the code work? Be specific and quit wasting peoples time with statement like that when they don't provide any helpful information. How can a working example not make any sense??? What part did you change that caused a problem???

Comment: Also, what part about my comment that variable names should NOT start with an upper case character ("CircleC") did NOT make sense? What part about super.paintComponent(g). should be at the start of the paintCompennt() method did not make sense. Pay attention to the advice!!! How are we supposed to explain anything when you don't pay attention to the most direct suggestions??.

Comment: I took off paintComponent because it keep erasing the board. Is there a way to keep it there without it erasing the board?

Comment: @Ski `Is there a way to keep it there without it erasing the board?` No, you should always clear the background and then you need to repaint what was there before. Swing painting is not meant to be incremental. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). Again 2 working examples are included.

Comment: My english isn't very good, so i have a hard time understanding examples if they're not explained in a very simple way.

Comment: The Swing tutorials are a simple as it gets. If you have a problem with a line of code then ask a specific question about that link of code, don't just ignore it. That is why you start with a working example because it is better structured than your code. Also, the examples use reasonable names? A class name should be descriptive. How is "P" a descriptive class name?

Comment: Oh that. First I named it Paint, but then I had to use static methods from Paint in another class, and i got tired of keeping typing Paint.methodName(), so i changed it to P so I can type it faster. Also, i read everything on that page, but where's the codes?

Comment: 1-, `i read everything on that page, but where's the codes?` Seriously? You don't see the "Get The Code" heading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main method is static. Your p object is not: it is an instance field of the P class. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throw InterruptedException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            P p = new P();
            p.repaint();
        }
    } );
}
```

You should always access Swing components from the event dispatch thread, which is why I put it all in a EventQueue invokeLater.

Comment: What does invokeLater(new runnable ) mean?

Comment: @ski InvokeLater ensures that the contents of run are executed within the context of the event dispatching thread. This is important as swing is not thread safe and you should never create or modify the outside of the context off the EDT

Comment: @Ski, `What does invokeLater(new runnable ) mean?` - already answered in your last question. Did you read the tutorial link on `Concurrency`.

Comment: Actually, i got it to work. But is there a way to make it so that the super.repaintComponent method doesn't erase the board everytime it paints over?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it from main() because you can't call non-static functions (repaint()) or use non-static variables inside a static method (main()).

Instead make the main class implement Runnable and use a thread:

```
Thread repaintThread = new Thread("some_name", this); // \
public void run(){                                    // |
   while(true){                                       // >-Theese shall be in the main class
       repaint();                                     // |
   }                                                  // |
}                                                     // /
repaintThread.start();    //this shall be in main()
```